# Load partial columns values to existing parquet data set

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, subset, parquet

I have a requirement to load the set of column values to existing parquet data set.

The specific scenario occurs when the hive table is created extracting  data from datawarehouse table with the required fields.

During some analysis some more columns in the DW table need to be added to hive table.

So we need to add only specific column to be appended to the existing data set without re-processing the whole file